# How to implement "NOT IN" in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notin, nosql

I have a dataset of objects, e.g. cars. I want to make a system where users are presented an object, and can decide whether or not they like the car. But, I want to show them each car only once.

```
- allCars
  - car1
  - car2
  ...
  - car348237

- carsLiked
  - user1
    - carsLiked
      - car123
      - car234
    - carsNotLiked
      - car321
  - user2
    - carsLiked
    - carsNotLiked
```

Given some user, e.g. user1, how can I make a selection from allCars, WHITOUT cars that the user has already seen? In SQL I would do something like " WHERE carId NOT IN (car123, car234, car321) "

Any idea how I can do this in firebase (without filtering on clientside, I know how to do that)...? Any structure possible, using some kind of index.? I struggled for sometime but didn't find a solution.

Comment: can you modify the data with a flag when they view it? that way, it should already be there for searching later...

Comment: Yes of course, but then I still don't know a way to present only cars that they haven't seen yet, without doing client side filtering.

Comment: It would be possible to just grab e.g. 100 cars from allCars. Then on client, remove all cars from the list that the user has already seen and show only the remaining cars. That is "the dirty way" which doesn't scale with large sets. And will not work well with relatively little allCars and large carsLiked. Plus, performance will degrade if user has seen e.g. 2000 cars. Thats why I don't want client side filtering..

Comment: you can store the clicks on another table, fetch the blacklist and a list of all IDs, then request the data for each one not banned. this is essentially the reverse of "load all filter client-side". as firebase says: "We want to provide a fully serverless experience, and we're working to add better querying capabilities to the core Firebase API."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "a list of all IDs" => do you mean in my example the IDs of ALL cars? Not nice if there are (100s) of thousands of them.

But if there is no other solution, then there is no other solution :-)

Comment: if the user has seen 2000 cars, the SQL way kinda sucks as well...

Answer (score 1):

Denormalization is a key.

I would replicate a set of all cars in each user's object and than I would delete the car object already displayed to user.

```
cars:{
  CAR_AUDO_ID: {
     //car object
  }

users:{
  user1:{
    car_selection:{
       CAR_AUTO_ID: true //reference to above
       ...
    },
    cars_liked:{
    },
    cars_disliked:{
    }
}
```

coming from SQL it might sound like a lot of replication, but that the way to go with firebase.

in case you have something like 10K+ cars, of course the above would be overkill. If users are presented a random car than I would focus on random number generator where I would store only already picked numbers. In that case the best would be to use priority ordered list and your key would be something like increment counter.